# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC super admin connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

Can someone help me with a superAdmin creation form in ASP.NET Core 5?

Here is my code. The user is created and roles too. But when I try to log in with the credentials, the `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method returns always false.

From the startup class I created this method for roles and the super admin:

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceprovider, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {            
        foreach (string rol in this.Configuration.GetSection("Roles").Get<List<string>>())
        {
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(rol))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(rol));
            }
                     
        }
        var poweruser = new ApplicationUser
        {

            UserName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PowerUser:Username"),
            Email = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PowerUser:Email")
        };
        string userPWD = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PowerUser:Password");
        string useremail = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PowerUser:Email");
        var _user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(useremail);
        if (_user == null)
        {
            var createPowerUser = await userManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, userPWD);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                //ApplicationUser users = userManager.Users.Where(u=>u.Email.Equals("mamadous@accessbankplc.com")).SingleOrDefault();
                //here we tie the new user to the role
          
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");
                ApplicationUser update = (from db in dbContext.Users
                                       where db.Email == "syllbailo2@gmail.com"
                                       select db).SingleOrDefault();
                update.role = "Admin";
                dbContext.SaveChanges();


            }
        }
    }
```

But when I try to connect I'm receiving false with:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Please any help?

Comment: Did you set up authentication correctly?

Comment: Hello @Chaodeng, i had a bad config on my appsetting file the username and the email has not the same content. now im fine thx

Comment: @Sylla I edited your question to correct spelling and punctuation. Before posting your question, please re-read it and edit for clarity. In this question, a snippet of PowerUser:Username, PowerUser:Password, and PowerUser:Email from your configuration file would have included helpful context. If you solve your own problem, please post your explanation as an answer, instead of a comment, and accept it so others are aware the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I had a bad configuration value on my `appsettings.json` file. The username and the email does not have the same content. Now I'm fine.

Content of my `appsettings.json` file:

```json
"PowerUser": 
{
    "Username": "xxx@gmail.com",
    "Email": "xxx@gmail.com",
    "Password": "xxx"
},
```

I replaced the username and email to have the same value, the same email, and it works now.

Thx.